# Querying many-to-many relationship returns nothing

Tags: django

I'm making a queryset:

```
def get_context_data(self, name, **kwargs):
    context = super(ListDetailsOfTestSuite, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['test_suite'] = TestSuite.objects.filter(name=name)
    temp = TestSuite.objects.get(name=name)
    context['test_cases'] = temp.test_cases.all()
    return context
```

models:

```
class TestCase(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    documentation = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True)
    steps = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    setup = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True)
    teardown = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True)
    template = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    timeout = models.IntegerField(default=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class TestSuite(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    documentation = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True)
    setup = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True)
    teardown = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True)
    force_tags = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    timeout = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    # user can have multiple test suites
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Suite can contain a list of test cases but also a number of other test suites
    test_cases = models.ManyToManyField(TestCase, through='SuiteCaseThroughModel')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)


class SuiteCaseThroughModel(OrderedModel):

    test_case = models.ForeignKey(TestCase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test_suite = models.ForeignKey(TestSuite, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    order_with_respect_to = 'test_suite'
```

However I'm getting nothing and I'm confident that the problem is in the filtering condition, because when I run `context['test_cases'] = TestCase.objects.all()` I get what I expect. The idea is to retrieve all test cases from a particular test suite, hence with little bit of research I came up with:

```
temp = TestSuite.objects.get(name=name)
context['test_cases'] = temp.test_cases.all()
```

html:

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    {% for field in test_suite %}
    {{ field.name }}
      <ul>
          <li><label>Documentation:</label>  {{ field.documentation }}</li>
          <li><label>Setup:</label>  {{ field.setup }}</li>
          <li><label>Teardown:</label>  {{ field.teardown }}</li>
          <li><label>Force Tags:</label>  {{ field.force_tags }}</li>
          <li><label>Timeout:</label>  {{ field.timeout }}</li>
     </ul>
</div>
{% endfor %}
<div class="col-md-6">
    {% for field in test_cases %}
    {{ field.name }}
    <ul>
        <li><label>Documentation:</label>  {{ field.documentation }}</li>
        <li><label>Setup:</label>  {{ field.setup }}</li>
        <li><label>Teardown:</label>  {{ field.teardown }}</li>
        <li><label>Tags:</label>  {{ field.tags }}</li>
        <li><label>Timeout:</label>  {{ field.timeout }}</li>
   </ul>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ListDetailsOfTestSuite, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['test_suite'] = TestSuite.objects.filter(name=kwargs['name']).prefetch_related('test_cases')
    temp = TestSuite.objects.get(name=kwargs['name'])
    context['test_cases'] = temp.test_cases.all()
    return context
```

I'm making two similar queries here because I need to render information about the test suite and its associated test cases on one page.

**TRIED:**

```
context['test_cases'] = TestCase.objects.filter(testsuite__name=kwargs['name'])
```

and also

```
context['test_cases'] = TestCase.objects.filter(suitecasethroughmodel__test_suite__name=kwargs['name'])
```

Django also supports lookups from the other side of query (or reverse lookups). Didn't help though, returns nothing.
I've got currently 1 test case related to the test suite that **should** be returned.

Comment: What do you have in your variable `name`? Can you print it? I don't think you should do that way. You should access your  `name` through `kwargs['name']`

Comment: Are you sure you linked the data correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you passing the `name` of your test through query string on your URL, you should do something like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch


def get_context_data(self, name, **kwargs):
    context = super(ListDetailsOfTestSuite, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['test_suite'] = TestSuite.objects.filter(name=kwargs['name']).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('test_cases', queryset=TestSuite.objects.all())
    )
    return context
```

Then from your `test_suite`, you can access your `test_cases` and this way you prevent more queries to run.

You can access `test_cases` through:

```py
for test in test_suite:
    print(test.test_cases.all())
```

Comment: I printed out what that gives me:  `{'name': 'What', 'view': <frontend.views.ListDetailsOfTestSuite object at 0x10daddf50>, 'test_suite': <QuerySet [<TestSuite: What>]>}` which captures the data about Test Suites but not about Test Cases associated with it.

Comment: You'd still need to access `test_cases` the way you were doing, however, this way above you prevent a lot of extra queries to run.

Comment: Still getting nothing returned from test cases. Will update my post to reflect changes.

Comment: `for test in test_suite:
    print(test.test_cases.all())` this returns an empty queryset.

Comment: Don't I need to incorporate the `SuiteCaseThroughModel` into the query condition somehow ? The class serves as a joiner between TestCase and TestSuite.

Comment: I've edited my answer but I'm not that sure if that would help. you can give it a try.

Comment: That throws an error `cannot resolve keyword testsuite`. I'm gonna have to do further research about querying databases with a joiner class.